# need help to show in 1 table all types ( Adress type , Number telephone VARRAY , other NESTED TABLE)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, nested

i have created a database that have :

```
Create Type T_Adresse as Object (  Rue VARCHAR2(30) , Ville
VARCHAR2(15) , Code_Postal VARCHAR2(5) );

Create Type t_NumTel as Object (  Num_Tel VARCHAR2(15)) ;

Create Type V_t_NumTel as  VARRAY(3) of t_NumTel ;

Create Type t_Diplome as object (  NDip VARCHAR2(20) , Titre VARCHAR2(50), Etablissement VARCHAR2(50) ) ;

Create Type TAB_t_Diplome as Table of t_Diplome ;

Create Type t_Candidat as object (  NCond number(6) ,  NomComplet VARCHAR2(30) , DateNais Date ,  Adresse t_Adresse ,  NumTel V_T_NumTel,  Diplomes TAB_t_Diplome  );

create Table Candidats of t_candidat( constraint PK_NCOND primary Key (NCond) , constraint CK_Nom_Complet CHECK (NomComplet is NOT NULL ) ,constraint CK_Date_Naiss CHECK  (DateNais is NOT NULL ) )     NESTEDTABLE Diplomes STORE AS TousDiplomes ;
```

now my problem is that when I make the select to all table it show me the the table repeated as the number of telephone number and diplomes like in this example of insert it show me

[image]

like you see it's repeated the informations

I would that I found someone help me to give me the correct SQL REQUET That give me all the number of telephone and diplomes and not repeated the first fixed informations

if you have something that you don't understand it, I can explain

Comment: please edit your question with sql which you use to select theese datas.

Comment: select c.NCOND , C.NOMCOMPLET , C.DATENAIS , C.ADRESSE.RUE , C.ADRESSE.VILLE , C.ADRESSE.Code_Postal  , AD.* , D.*

from Candidats C , TABLE (C.NumTel) AD , TABLE (C.DIPLOMES) D 

where NCond = 1

Comment: ` Insert into CANDIDATS 
(NOMCOMPLET,DATENAIS,ADRESSE,NUMTEL,DIPLOMES)
VALUES ( 
'james blint ',
DATE '1971-09-14', 
T_ADRESSE('aaaaaa','bbbbb','06000'), 
V_T_NUMTEL(
T_NUMTEL('0123456789') , 
T_NUMTEL('098765432') , 
T_NUMTEL('0123789456')) , 
TAB_T_Diplome(
T_Diplome('20141707','BAC','SCHOOL') ,
T_Diplome('20171135','License Finance','university'))
) ; `@BarbarosÖzhan

Answer (score 1):

** start opinion:

No wonder you're confused.  Oracle works best as a relational database.  Nested tables are a terrible idea and you should never use them.  We have perfectly good ways to deal with the structures implied by nested tables.  I'm not keen on defining table types either; why introduce another level of complexity?  Arrays are just another alternative to the standard relational approach, and I never use them.

If you wanted to normalise the telephone numbers out into a separate table, that would be OK, but if you are defining a fixed maximum of 3 telephone numbers, then the way I have done it is fine.  I would check that this is a genuine requirement though.

Below is a standard relational approach.  It solves your problem and I think it is much easier to understand.

** end opinion

```
create table candidat
(
    n_cond                 number(6.0),
    nom_complet            varchar2(30)    not null, 
    date_nais              date,
    rue                    varchar2(30), 
    ville                  varchar2(15),
    code_postal            varchar2(5), 
    num_tel_1              varchar2(15),
    num_tel_2              varchar2(15),
    num_tel_3              varchar2(15),
    constraint pk_ncond    primary key (n_cond) 
);

create sequence candidat_sequence;

create table diplome
(
    id_dip                 number(6.0),
    n_dip                  varchar2(20), 
    titre                  varchar2(50),
    etablissement          varchar2(50),
    constraint pk_diplome  primary key (id_dip)
);

create sequence diplome_sequence;

create table candidat_diplome
(
    n_cond                 number(6,0),
    id_dip                 number(6,0)
); 

insert into diplome 
(
    id_dip,
    n_dip,
    titre,
    etablissement
) 
values 
(
    diplome_sequence.nextval,  -- id_dip
    '20141707',                -- n_dip
    'BAC',                     -- titre
    'SCHOOL'                   -- etablissement
);

insert into diplome 
(
    id_dip,
    n_dip,
    titre,
    etablissement
) 
values 
(
    diplome_sequence.nextval,  -- id_dip
    '20171135',                -- n_dip
    'license',                 -- titre
    'univerty'                 -- etablissement
);

insert into candidat
(
    n_cond,
    nom_complet, 
    date_nais,
    rue, 
    ville,
    code_postal, 
    num_tel_1,
    num_tel_2,
    num_tel_3
)
values
(
    candidat_sequence.nextval,            -- n_cond
    'james blint',                        -- nom_complet
    to_date('1971-09-14', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),  -- date_nais
    'aaaaaa',                             -- rue 
    'bbbbb',                              -- ville
    '06000',                              -- code_postal 
    '0123456789',                         -- num_tel_1
    '0987654321',                         -- num_tel_2
    '0123789456'                          -- num_tel_3
);

insert into candidat_diplome (n_cond, id_dip) values (1, 1);
insert into candidat_diplome (n_cond, id_dip) values (1, 2);

select
    a.n_cond,
    a.nom_complet, 
    a.date_nais,
    a.rue, 
    a.ville,
    a.code_postal, 
    a.num_tel_1,
    a.num_tel_2,
    a.num_tel_3,
    b.n_dip,
    b.titre,
    b.etablissement
from
    candidat a
    join
    candidat_diplome c on a.n_cond = c.n_cond
    join
    diplome b on b.id_dip = c.id_dip;

N_COND NOM_COMPLET DATE_NAIS RUE    VILLE CODE_ NUM_TEL_1  NUM_TEL_2  NUM_TEL_3  N_DIP    TITRE   ETABLISSEMENT
------ ----------- ---------------- ----- ----- ---- ----  ---------- ---------- -------- ------- -------------
     1 james blint 14-SEP-71 aaaaaa bbbbb 06000 0123456789 0987654321 0123789456 20141707 BAC     SCHOOL
     1 james blint 14-SEP-71 aaaaaa bbbbb 06000 0123456789 0987654321 0123789456 20171135 license univerty
```